# Convert .haml to .html in Notepad++?

Tags: ruby, notepad++

How do I set up Notepad++ to automatically run the console line "haml [filename.haml] [filename.html]" every time I update and save a .haml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the Python Script plugin - just add a new script as

```
notepad.clearCallbacks([NOTIFICATION.FILESAVED])

# Define the function to call just after the file is saved
def runHaml(args):
    filename = notepad.getBufferFilename(args["bufferID"])
    if filename[-5:] == '.haml':
        cmd = r'cmd /c C:\path\to\haml "{0}" "{1}.html"'.format(filename, filename[:-5])
        console.write(cmd + "\n")
        console.run(cmd)


# ... and register the callback 
notepad.callback(runHaml, [NOTIFICATION.FILESAVED])
```

You can add this to the startup.py to get it to automatically run this at startup (change the configuration of Python Script to "ATSTARTUP" too).

Answer (score 1):

What about using something like a [watchr](http://github.com/mynyml/watchr) script?

Something like:

```
watch( '(.*)\.haml' ) do |md|
  system("haml #{md[0]} #{md[1]}.html")
end
```

Should automatically recompile your html file whenever the source haml changes.